# React.js AWS Appysync Query Items

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm currently working with GraphQL Appsync in AWS Amplify and I was wondering if there is a way to specify the items I want to return.

Right now, I'm using the following to fetch a response but it returns all the parameters in the defined schema.

```js
const fetchResponse = async () => {
  const oneResponse = await API.graphql({
    query: queries.getResponse,
    variables: { id: responseId },
  });
  console.log(fetchResponse);
};
```

How do I specify to only return certain parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new query. The current queries provided upon schema creation can be used, but are typically used as examples.

Go to your queries file, and then copy the query you're using `queries.getResponse`.

```
query getResponse($blogId:ID!) {
  getResponse(id:$blogId) {
    id
    name
    posts {
      items {
        id
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Choose the items you would like for the graphql to return.